# How to use CSV column as key in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Right now I'm using PHPSpreadsheets to load a CSV into a multidimensional array with a lot of `for loops`. In the CSV file a new row starts with what the data next to it stands for.

Is there a way to use those cells as  keys in the array? Right now the code is not dynamic at all and I want to change that.

```
Question 1.1 Example One : 2 : 3 : 4
Question 1.1 Example Two : 2 : 3 : 4
Question 1.1 Example Three : 2 : 3 : 4
```

Like that. I need Question 1.1 to be the key.

```
for( $x = 'B', $vragenTellen = 2; $x <= $highestColumn; $x++, $vragenTellen++){
    ${"competentie111vraag$vragenTellen"}= $spreadsheet1->getActiveSheet()->RangeToArray(
    ''.$x.'2'.':'.$x.$highestColumnForQuestions.'',  
    NULL,        
    FALSE,        
    TRUE,        
    TRUE         
    );
    }
```

This is what I have right now to load in the rows with data. 
But I can't think of a way to connect the rows with the corresponding name.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What code have you written? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried looking for a way to do it. But haven't been able to so far. Right now I am just writing the keys by hand.

Comment: Added some code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved my issue was by taking the code I put up in my question and telling it to only take the column that has the questions, turning it into an array.

Then later I created a `for loop` and used the question-array as the filler for the `$keys`. This way my multi-dimensional array has all the questions and answers that go with it.